# addSubview waits for rest of method

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I would like show my view immediately when I call it. I don't know how to make the view show.

```
-(IBAction) showProgress: (id) sender {
   progressViewController *progress = [[progressViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"progressViewController" bundle:NULL];
   [self.view addSubview:progress.view];
   [self someFunctionWhichTakesAgesToBeDone];
}
```

It's called from current UIViewController. And the view appears after the long function. How can I show it before the long funcion? Thanks for answer.

Comment: If you want to show your view immediately, why are you calling `sleep()`?

Comment: I have there HTTP request which take 3 seconds to be done. So I change it for sleep for better lucidity.

Comment: "better lucidity"? What does that mean? Also, why would you want to block while waiting for an HTTP Request?

Comment: I want show new view while program is waiting for response and the view appears after the response...

Comment: it doesn't need to sleep() to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`
```

use

```
[self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:progress.view waitUntilDone:YES]
```

or put your Sleep() function (i hope it's anything else, Sleep() func is really bad, as its been told) into another function `MySleepFunc` and call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(MySleepFunc) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.003]
```

instead of Sleep(3).

Comment: Glad it helped, but remove your Sleep() function ASAP :)

Comment: you really should check grand central dispatch instead of the performSelector stuff.

Comment: @Bastian is right. Upvoting and forcing you to check this stuff. =D

Answer (score 1):

Use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) which is the simplest way (and recommended by Apple), the code will then be:

```
-(IBAction) showProgress: (id) sender {
    progressViewController *progress = [[progressViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"progressViewController" bundle:NULL];
    [self.view addSubview:progress.view];

    // Heavy work dispatched to a separate thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"dispatched");
        // Do heavy or time consuming work
        [self someFunctionWhichTakesAgesToBeDone];

        // When finished call back on the main thread:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Return data and update on the main thread
        });
    });

}
```

It´s two blocks. The first one does the heavy work on a separate thread and then a second block is called when the heavy work is finished so that changes and UI updates are done on the main thread, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Read about multi-threading. In short, there's single UI thread that does drawing, accepting user events and so on. If you pause it with sleep() or any other blocking method, nothing will be shown/redrawn and no events will be processed. You have to make your HTTP request from background thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be solution.